# Can i access 127.0.0.2 3 etc from another computer/network over LAN?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, lan

I have 2 computers(X n Y) which connected with same wifi/LAN. If i want to access my localhost(127.0.0.1) from computer X to Y i just enter LAN IP(example http://192.168.99.5) on computer Y. But how to access 127.0.0.2 or 127.0.0.3 etc to other computer?